# Program opens on disconnected and invisible monitor

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, display, windows-8-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover Windows Opening Off Screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/477095/recover-windows-opening-off-screen)

I'm working with a HP Elitebook 8460p with Windows 8 using always 2 Monitors connected. And some Programs I'm always opening on the second screen (which windows does automatically).

But now the problem: When the screens aren't connected (when I'm at home), some programs still open on the second screen (which does not exist anymore) and it's just not possible to move them to the main (only!) screen!

Does some one knows a solution for the problem - already bringing back the windows to the main screen would be enough.
Thanks

Comment: Try Windows+P a few times, select Single-Monitor or Duplicate

Comment: Nice function Windows+P, but does not solve the problem. My beloved program stays hidden on the invisible screen :-(

Comment: This sounds like a job for a functioning Operating System to do on its own. I wonder how we got convinced to work around it forever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A workaround/solution is easy: Resize your current resolution at home. This will bring all open programs onto the single screen. Then change back to the desired resolution.

Also see [this similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/477095/recover-windows-opening-off-screen/) where the correct answer is listed:

> Click the icon in the taskbar to ensure that the program has focus. Then hold down the Windows key and press the right-arrow a few times. That should move the window across your screens and eventually bring it back onto the screen that is still active. [Original technet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/f3040564-0457-4c91-af71-dce1bc673a99)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the similar question! There someone had the correct answer: Clicking on the hidden program in the taskbar and then using Windows+Left or Windows+Right arrow key to rearrange the programs. (Changing resolution does not work)

Comment: Changing resolutions always worked for me on windows XP. I just tested it on windows 7 and indeed it failed. I guess my knowledge was outdated.  (Playing around with enabling and disabling extended display etc did work, but that really is a kludge).

Comment: Fast forward to Windows 11 and neither of these options works for me (Google Earth). Unfortunate that there isn't a master App Window view.